# PHP not writing to file from one source

Tags: php, file

I have an issue I can't seem to find the solution for. I am trying to write to a flat text file. I have echoed all variables out on the screen, verified permissions for the user (www-data) and just for grins set everything in the whole folder to 777 - all to no avail. Worst part is I can call on the same function from another file and it writes. I can't see to find the common thread here.....

```
function ReplaceAreaInFile($AreaStart, $AreaEnd, $File, $ReplaceWith){
$FileContents = GetFileAsString($File);
$Section = GetAreaFromFile($AreaStart, $AreaEnd, $FileContents, TRUE);
if(isset($Section)){
    $SectionTop = $AreaStart."\n";
    $SectionTop .= $ReplaceWith;
    $NewContents = str_replace($Section, $SectionTop, $FileContents);

    if (!$Handle = fopen($File, 'w')) {
        return "Cannot open file ($File)";
        exit;
    }/*
    if(!flock($Handle, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {
        echo 'Unable to obtain file lock';
        exit(-1);
    }*/
    if (fwrite($Handle, $NewContents) === FALSE) {
        return "Cannot write to file ($File)";
        exit;
    }else{
        return $NewContents;
    }
}else{
        return "<p align=\"center\">There was an issue saving your settings. Please try again. If the issue persists contact your provider.</p>";
}
}
```

Comment: Which return statement do you hit?

Comment: It successfully returns the $NewContents variable - but nothing gets written to the file. I also know the file path is good because it gets the existing contents of the file and replaces the desired section in the returned variable.

Comment: How many bytes does fwrite say it wrote?   Also should you be closing the file with fclose($Handle)?

Answer (score 0):

Try with...

```
$Handle = fopen($File, 'w');
if ($Handle === false) {
    die("Cannot open file ($File)");
}
$written = fwrite($Handle, $NewContents);
if ($written === false) {
    die("Invalid arguments - could not write to file ($File)");
}
if ((strlen($NewContents) > 0) && ($written < strlen($NewContents))) {
    die("There was a problem writing to $File - $written chars written");
}
fclose($Handle);
echo "Wrote $written bytes to $File\n"; // or log to a file
return $NewContents;
```

and also check for any problems in the error log. There should be something, assuming you've enabled error logging.

You need to check for number of characters written since in PHP fwrite behaves like this:

> After having problems with fwrite() returning 0 in cases where one
>   would fully expect a return value of false, I took a look at the
>   source code for php's fwrite() itself. The function will only return
>   false if you pass in invalid arguments. Any other error, just as a
>   broken pipe or closed connection, will result in a return value of
>   less than strlen($string), in most cases 0.

Also, note that you might be writing to a file, but to a different file that you're expecting to write. Absolute paths might help with tracking this.

Comment: After all the fighting with the fwrite command, I managed to solve the issue with this being the command writing to the files:          file_put_contents($File2WriteName, $ContentsForFile, LOCK_EX);

Answer (score 0):

The final solution I ended up using for this:

```
function ReplaceAreaInFile($AreaStart, $AreaEnd, $File, $ReplaceWith){
    $FileContents = GetFileAsString($File);
    $Section = GetAreaFromFile($AreaStart, $AreaEnd, $FileContents, TRUE);
    if(isset($Section)){
        $SectionTop = $AreaStart."\n";
        $SectionTop .= $ReplaceWith;
        $NewContents = str_replace($Section, $SectionTop, $FileContents);
        return $NewContents;
    }else{
        return "<p align=\"center\">There was an issue saving your settings.</p>";
    }
}

function WriteNewConfigToFile($File2WriteName, $ContentsForFile){
    file_put_contents($File2WriteName, $ContentsForFile, LOCK_EX);
}
```

I did end up using absolute file paths and had to check the permissions on the files. I had to make sure the www-data user in Apache was able to write to the files and was also the user running the script.